# Commutation of limits of double sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider sequence $a_{nm}$ such that $a_{nm} \overset{n}{\rightarrow} a_m$ and $a_{im} \leq a_{jm}  \;\;\forall\; i<j$.

We also have $a_{m} \overset{m}{\rightarrow} a$ and $a_{p} \leq a_{q} \;\;\forall \;p<q$. Then, is it possible to prove that,

$\lim_n \lim_m a_{nm} = \lim_m \lim_n a_{nm} = a$

If not, then what are the conditions under which the limits commute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a_{nm}=2-(1/2)^n$ if $m$ is odd and $a_{nm}=2-(1/2)^{n+1}$ otherwise. Then for fixed $n$ the sequence $(a_{nm})_m$ oscilates, so you cannot consider the inner limit $\lim_m a_{nm}$.

Comment: What are the conditions under which the limits can commute?

Comment: Thanks. Another example would be $a_{nm} = (1-(1/2)^m)^n$.
$\lim_m \lim_n a_{nm} = 0$ but $\lim_n \lim_m a_{nm} = 1$

Comment: @user167291 I am afraid that your proposed sequence cannot be used as counterexample: in fact, for fixed $m$ your sequence $(a_{nm})$ is *decreasing* as function of $n$. Regarding sufficient conditions, i didn't think yet.